# How to blur the span attribute in angular

Tags: angular, blur

I want to blur the span element having test "Blur me" whenever I click on checkbox

html file

```
 <input (click)="clickbox()" type="checkbox">
 <span>
   <span class="blur"> Blur Me </span>
   <input [disabled]="ischecked" type="month">
 </span>
```

TS file

```
ischecked = true;
clickbox() {
  console.log(this.ischecked);
  this.ischecked = !this.ischecked;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html:

```
<span [class.blurred]="isChecked">
</span>
```

And add a class into styles with the following code:

```
.blurred {
    color: darkgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
component.html

```
<input (click)="clickbox()" type="checkbox">
 <span>
   <span [ngClass]="(!ischecked) ? '': 'blur'"> Blur Me </span>
   <input [disabled]="ischecked" type="month">
 </span>
```

component.css

```
.blur {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

component.ts

```
clickbox() {
  console.log(this.ischecked);
  this.ischecked = !this.ischecked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngClass directive to toggle a class like this

```
 <span [ngClass]="{blur:ischecked }" > Blur Me </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update this line in code

```
<span class="blur"> Blur Me </span>
```

to this

```
<span [ngClass]="{'blur': ischecked}"> Blur Me </span>
```